# Trying to Create a Execuatble JAR from a Maven Web App, when I run it nothing happens

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jar, tomcat7

I created a web app and when I run it as a normal war file with tomcat7:run I can open my browser and go to localhost:8080 and use the complete app, I now want to make it deploy-able so I used tomcat7:exec-war and set up then pom.xml file as follows:

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.Dictionary</groupId>
  <artifactId>DistributedSystemsProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/</path>
                        <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                        <enableNaming>false</enableNaming>
                        <finalName>dictionary-service.jar</finalName>
                        <charset>utf-8</charset>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

this creates a JAR file in the workspace but when I run it I get the following:

```
Dec 21, 2017 2:02:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 21, 2017 2:02:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Dec 21, 2017 2:02:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Dec 21, 2017 2:02:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

Then when I go to local host 8080 i get a page not found response, if anyone could help me with this id greatly appreciate it as im lost and cant find anything online.